# Replace string with \ not work in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, replace, str-replace, rtf, non-ascii-characters

On my project I need to import from clipboard excel data.
But in case we have german chars like "ä ö ü" I need to replace.

[image]

```cs
clipboardText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf);
clipboardText.Replace("\u252\'fc", "ü");
```

but why this not works?

[image]

Comment: `String.Replace()` is a function - it returns the new result.

Comment: It doesn't like \\'